# Making nuxt link Vuetify primary theme color

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I would like for NuxtLink to be the themes primary color and for this to be set globally (ideally)

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Some effort is expected from you here.

Answer (score 0):

```
theme: {
  defaultTheme: 'light',
  themes: {
    light: {
      dark: false,
      colors: {
        primary: '#000000'
      },
    },
    dark: {
      dark: true,
      colors: {
        primary: '#ffffff'
      },
    },
  }
}

<NuxtLink to="" class="text-primary">Link</NuxtLink>
```

This wasn't working originally because my createVuetify() was not set up properly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).